prove $\sin\left(x\right)\ \le x-\frac{x^3}{3\ !}+\frac{x^5}{5!}$
prove $$\sin\left(x\right)\ \le x-\frac{x^3}{3 !}+\frac{x^5}{5!}$$
if $x \geq 0$.
Taking its derivative, I get
$$\cos(x)\leq 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}- \frac{x^4}{4!}$$
Or do I have to solve
$$-2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})\leq -\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}$$
which doesn't help much
Instead I noticed that $$\sin(x)-x \leq 0
$$
which implies that $0 \leq -\frac{x^3}{3!}+ \frac{x^5}{5!}$ is what I have to solve
Which gives me the incorrect answer. Why is this wrong?

Derivatives doesn't preserve inequalities. $f(x) \le g(x)$ does not imply or is implied by $f'(x) \le g'(x)$.

Err, yes it is, kinda. If $f(0)\leq g(0)$ and $f’(x)\leq g’(x)$ for $x\geq 0$, then $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for $x\geq 0$. Repeat 5 times to get the desired result.

@Eric, why do I have to take the derivative 5 times?

@Eric Well, yes, if you add more hypothesis then it's true.

Because it’ll reduce the $x^5/5!$ term which is hard to deal with to $1$ which is easy to deal with.
@jjagmath Agreed. My main point is that (contrary to your comment) taking derivatives can potentially lead to a valid solution if you’re careful.

@Eric but it is not that derivatives preserve inequalities. You are proving an inequality about derivatives, and integrating.

What's your definition of $\sin x$?

Let $f(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \sin x$, and we have to show that $f(x) \geq 0$ if $x \geq 0$.
Note that $f(0)=0$. We will be done if we can show that $f(x)$ is increasing in the interval $[0,\infty)$.
Note that $f'(x)= 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \cos x$. We will be done if we can show that $f'(x) \geq 0$ in the interval $[0,\infty)$.
Note that $f'(0)=0$. We will be done if we can show that $f'(x)$ increases in $[0,\infty)$.
So we will be done if we can prove that $f''(x) \geq 0$ in the interval $[0,\infty)$.
Note that $f''(x)= -x + \frac{x^3}{3!}  +\sin x$. Since $f''(0)=0$, we will be done if we can show that $f'''(x) \geq 0$ on $[0,\infty)$.
Note that $f'''(x)= -1 + \frac{x^2}{2!}  +\cos x$. Since $f'''(0)=0$, we will be done if we can show that $f^{''''}(x) \geq 0$ on $[0,\infty)$.
Finally, $f''''(x)= x  - \sin x \geq 0$. Hence proved.
Different Approach:
Observe that, $\sin x \leq x$, integrating both side over $(0,t)$, we get $1 - \cos t \leq \frac{t^2}{2!} \implies 1 - \frac{t^2}{2!} \leq \cos t \leq 1$,
Integrating both side again over $(0,x)$, we get $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \leq \sin x \leq x$
Integrating both side again over $(0,t)$, we get $\frac{t^2}{2!} - \frac{t^4}{4!} \leq 1 - \cos t \leq \frac{t^2}{2!} \iff 1 - \frac{t^2}{2!} \leq \cos t \leq 1 - \frac{t^2}{2!} + \frac{t^4}{4!}$
Finally after integrating both side again over $(0,x)$, we get $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \leq \sin x \leq x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}$

After integrating and applying this procedure, we can also easily generalize the result.

We have $(\sin t)^{(5)}=\cos t. $ Hence by the MacLaurin formula for $n=5$ and $x>0$ we get $$\sin x=x-{x^3\over 3!}+{x^5\over 5!}\cos(\zeta)\\ \le x-{x^3\over 3!}+ {x^5\over 5!}$$
Remark The same reasoning gives $$\sin x\le \sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^{k}{x^{2k+1}\over (2k+1)!},\ x>0$$
$$\sin x\ge \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k}{x^{2k+1}\over (2k+1)!},\ x>0$$

Please crosspost your answer here.
